# my iphone shows "sent as text message"

Tags: messages, text

messages I send from my iphone 4 are showing as "sent as text message" I've read all the responses but no one mentions if my messages are actually being received. How can I tell if receipient is actually recieving my message?

Answer (score 2):

The "sent as text message" means your text message was sent using SMS, not iMessage. Because the message wasn't sent through iMessage, neither you or the person you are texting to have access to read receipts, which allow you to see whether or not the person you sent the text message to read your message.

This often happens if you're in an area with bad signal, with no access to wifi, 3G, or LTE coverage and the message can only be sent via SMS.

Answer (score 0):

This happens with the phone is unable to send the message via iMessage, so it will fall back to standard SMS text messaging.

If they got the message? Only sure fire way is to call the recipient I suspect.